# Cannot read property 'fqn' of undefined for UIView (UIRouter 2+) for Karma/Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Our environment:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 6.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.0
@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.4.0
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
@uirouter/angular@1.0.1
| +-- @uirouter/core@5.0.17
| `-- @uirouter/rx@0.4.5
```

When a testing a secondary component (one that does not contain the root ui-view of the module) that includes a ui-view my tests are failing with the error 'Cannot read property 'fqn' of undefined'.

The following is the test including a failed attempt at mocking the UIView:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UiviewWrappedComponent } from './uiview-wrapped.component';
import {UIRouter, UIRouterModule, UIView} from '@uirouter/angular';
import createSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj;

describe('UiviewWrappedComponent', () => {
  let component: UiviewWrappedComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UiviewWrappedComponent>;
  const mUiView1 = createSpyObj('UIView.PARENT_INJECT', ['onBefore']);


  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [UIRouterModule],
      declarations: [ UiviewWrappedComponent ],
      providers: [{provide: UIRouter, useClass:
        class { mockUIRouter = new UIRouter(); }},
        {provide: UIView.PARENT_INJECT, useFunction: {mUiView1}},
        {provide: 'UIViewDirective', useClass: class {mockUIView = new 
         UIView(new UIRouter(), new ParentFqn(), null); }}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UiviewWrappedComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

export class ParentFqn {
  public fqn = 'state';
  public parentFqn = 'blah';
}
```

// the html

```
<ui-view>
<p>
  uiview-wrapped works!
</p>
</ui-view>
```

Looking at the uiView.js file it appears that the injected parent is assumed to be defined within ngOnInit but the assigned parentFqn var is not... Not sure what that means but my attempts to mock this have proven unsuccessful.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to import UIRouterModule.forRoot() into the test and add {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' } to the test provider list.